# LINQ query using join and aggregate functions

Tags: linq-to-sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, having

Urgh...my LINQ has suddenly taken a turn for the worse!!

I have two tables and want to join and perform aggregate functions upon the tables.

Firstly, is this possible, I am assuming it is, and secondly, how do I handle the aggregate functions? As part of the same LINQ statement?

The SQL statement will look a bit like this:

```
SELECT     t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t2.Col10, 
                      t2.Col11, SUM(t2.Col4) AS TotalPurchases, COUNT(t1.Col5) AS ProductCount,t2.Col7, 
                      t2.Col6, t2.Col8, t2.Col9
FROM         t1 INNER JOIN
                      t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col5 = t2.Col5 AND 
                      t1.Col2 = t2.Col2
GROUP BY t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t2.Col7, t2.Col6, 
                      t2.Col8, t2.Col9, t2.Col10, t2.Col11
HAVING      (t1.Col1 = @p1) AND (t1.Col2 = @p2) AND (t1.Col3 = @p3)
```

Obviously, the 'AS' sections can be ignored, I can rename those in the controls.

Any hints, tips, pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something as below make use of joins with the `into` keyword help you to achieve your taks

```
var query = from t1 in prodDtcx.t1
            join t2 in prodDtcx.t2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID
            group t1.col1,t2.col2 by new {col1= t1.col1,col2=  t2.col2,col3 = t1.col2} into g
            where g.col3 >= @variable
            select new { Col1 = g.col1, Col2 = g.col2};
```

Check this post for more detail : [LINQ Having Clause and Group By with condition](http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2009/09/17/linq-having-clause-and-group-by-with-condition.aspx)